# "SMTP Error: Could not authenticate" in PHPMailer with Gmail

Tags: gmail, phpmailer

I know similiar question has been asked many times and I already read many of them.

Mine is different.

So I have a website that occasionary need to send email. I'm using PHPMailer with Gmail as SMTP. It's working great but after few days working, it will throw an error: "SMTP Error: Could not authenticate". To solve that, I need to do a manual login. Sometime with captcha. After few days, it will throw the same error.

What happening is Gmail block or temporary disable the account. How to solve this? Or should I use another SMTP (outlook.com ?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Gmail used to add captcha to prevent bad request to your account  .You can fix this issue by following these three simple steps

1. Disable Captcha Here's   https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
2. Create a strong password
3. Allow your gmail account for less secure app access Here's a link    https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapp